# CKEditor 4 - cannot replace selection

Tags: ckeditor

I desperately try to replace the selection (selected text) of a CKEditor instance

I tried like 10 different ways, most of the examples I found on the web lead to errors and undefined

here : a.getName is not a function

"a" beeing the "element" parameter of the 4th line for insertElement function

```
    let editor=window.CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;
    var range = editor.createRange();
    let element = window.CKEDITOR.dom.element.createFromHtml( "test" );
    editor.insertElement( element, range ); <<< culprit line
```

I tested this but it gives me an error :

```
    let editor=window.CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;
    var range = editor.createRange();
    editor.insertHtml( "test"+imageId,'html', range );
```

I also tried :

```
    editor.insertHtml( "test"+imageId,'text', range );
```

Comment: Use [insertHtml()](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/latest/api/CKEDITOR_editor.html#method-insertHtml)

Comment: I get "Cannot read property 'type' of null at new CKEDITOR.dom.elementPath" (I updated my question)

Comment: ok it works without giving a type nor a range, donct know why... generaly speaking , ckeditor produces errors that are not really pointing the programmer towards a solution...which is quiet frustrating

Comment: and yet I cannot post any answer, this is just ludicrous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `editor.insertHtml('<p>This is a new paragraph.</p>');` it will replace the current selection with this new html, no need for type or range in your case.

Comment: yes, I already posted then answer in the comment, since I cant bloody do it in the anser itself..thanks